# can not set color in InstancedMesh in three.js 125 version

Tags: three.js

I am trying in Three.js v-125 to randomly change the color of an instance of an instancedMesh as followed

```
    addSphere(){

        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 32);
        let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x8cde0d,});
        this.stars2 = new THREE.InstancedMesh(geometry, material,1000);
        let o3d = new THREE.Object3D();
        let position = new THREE.Vector3();
        let color = new THREE.Color();
        this.stars2.instanceMatrix.setUsage( THREE.DynamicDrawUsage ); 

        for (let i = 0; i < 6000; i++) {
            const random = +(Math.random() * 10).toFixed(0);
            let colorValue = 0x8cde0d;           
            position.set(
                Math.random() * 800 - 500,
                Math.random() * 800 - 500,
                Math.random() * 800 - 500
            )
            o3d.position.copy(position)
            o3d.updateMatrix()
            this.stars2.setMatrixAt(i++, o3d.matrix);

            //this.stars2.setColorAt(i, color.setHex( colorValue ));
            //this.stars2.setColorAt( i, color.setHex( 0xffffff * Math.random() ) );
              this.stars2.setColorAt( i, color.set(0xffffff * Math.random()));

        }
          this.stars2.instanceColor.needsUpdate = true;
          this.stars2.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;
          this.scene.add(this.stars2);

    }
```

I tried three different ways

```
    this.stars2.setColorAt(i, color.setHex( colorValue ));
    this.stars2.setColorAt( i, color.setHex( 0xffffff * Math.random() ) );
    this.stars2.setColorAt( i, color.set(0xffffff * Math.random()));
```

but none of them works, kind of strange how to do it in the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

> stars2.setColorAt(i, color.setHex( 0xffffff * Math.random() ));

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;

init();
render();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 1000;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10, 8, 8);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
  const stars2 = new THREE.InstancedMesh(geometry, material, 1000);

  const o3d = new THREE.Object3D();
  const position = new THREE.Vector3();
  const color = new THREE.Color();

  for (let i = 0; i < stars2.count; i++) {
    position.set(
      Math.random() * 800 - 400,
      Math.random() * 800 - 400,
      Math.random() * 800 - 400
    )

    o3d.position.copy(position)
    o3d.updateMatrix()
    
    stars2.setMatrixAt(i, o3d.matrix);
    stars2.setColorAt(i, color.setHex( 0xffffff * Math.random() ));

  }

  scene.add(stars2);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function render() {

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.125.2/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

There are two bugs in your code which prevent your app from working:

- You define 1000 instances but iterate over 6000.
- You increment the loop variable inside the loop again. That means your indexing is completely off.

Comment: thanks, as you said it is the indexing issue

Comment: i found that it needs to init the color at every index, or you cannot set color later. is this a routine or a limit of tech?